# React/Craco build: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'm' before initialization

Tags: reactjs, build, craco

Having an strange issue with my react application.

The application runs fine on "npm start", but has following error on build:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'm' before initialization"
```

This is a project we have been working on some time, and this is the first time we experience this issue.

It looks something like this in the output `js`:

```
var n.d(t,"b",(function(){return m})),m={};
```

Where variable "m" is declared after usecase.

```
React 18.0.2
Craco 6.4.5
```